# Copy the nth column of all the files in a directory into a single file

Tags: python, bash, awk

I've a directory containing many .csv files. How can I extract the nth column of every file into a new file column-wise?

For example:

File A:

```
111,222,333
111,222,333
```

File B:

```
AAA,BBB,CCC
AAA,BBB,CCC
```

File C:

```
123,456,789
456,342,122
```

and so on...

If n = 2, I want my resultant file to be:

```
222,BBB,456,... 
222,BBB,342,...
```

where `...` represents that there will be as many columns as the number of files in the directory.

My try so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `find ./ -iname "*.csv"`
  do
    awk -F, '{ print $2}' < $i >> result.csv ## This would append row-wise, not column-wise.
  done
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm not trying to just join two files. There are 100 of files in a particular directory, and I want to copy the nth column of all the files into a single file. I gave two files as an example to show how I want the data to be if there were only two files.

As pointed out in the comments, joining two files is trivial but joining multiple files may be not that easy which is the whole point of my question. Would python help to do this job?

Comment: Guys, I'd appreciate if you leave a comment when you downvote a question or else there is no way for people to improve. Is the question ambiguos or is there a solution that already exists or is the formatting of my question wrong?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, and I actually looked briefly for an obvious duplicate and could not find one; but this type of question is extremely frequent, here and on other sites, so I would assume that's the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Building on triplee's solution, here's a generic version which uses eval:

`eval paste -d, $(printf "<(cut -d, -f2 %s) " *.csv)`

I'm not too fond of eval (always be careful when using it), but it has its uses.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  My first thought is to have both an outer and inner loop.  The outer loop would be a counter on line number.  The inner loop would go through the csv files.  You'd need to use head/tail in the inner loop to get the correct line number so you could grab the right field.

An alternative is to use the one loop you have now but write each line to a separate file and then merge them.

Neither of these seem ideal.  Quite honestly, I'd do this in Perl so you could use an actual in memory data structure and avoid the need to have complex logic.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Bash process substitutions are acceptable (i.e. you don't require the solution to be portable to systems where Bash is not available);

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f2 file1) <(cut -d, -f2 file2) <(cut -d, -f2 file3) # etc
```

A POSIX solution requires temporary files instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not generalise to more than two files, which is what OP wants.

Comment: @KonradRudolph How does it not? Just add more columns as required. See updated answer.

Comment: You are hard-coding the files. What if you can’t do that?

Comment: Maybe generate them somehow, like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27110021/874188 ... But that goes for any situation where you are dealing with dynamic inputs.

Comment: `eval paste -d, $(for i in *.csv; do echo -n "<(cut -d, -f2 $i) "; done)`

Comment: @Aissen Pretty good! I think you could avoid the `for` loop with `printf`. If the files are not named for lexical sorting, you want a wildcard which enforces numeric sort order, like maybe `f[19].csv f[1-9][0-9].csv f[1-9][0-9][0-9].csv`

Comment: Ah, I see now that I already did that in the linked answer (-:

Comment: @tripleee : Nice, I didn't know shell-printf re-used the format until all arguments were consumed. Is that a bash only feature ? Anyway, I'll post an enhanced solution.

Comment: @triplee: I don't think OP required lexical sorting, so I just used *.csv.

Comment: No, `printf` is pretty much POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

this one liner should work:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2;next}{print a[FNR],$2}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not generalise to more than two files, which is what OP wants.